# How to set value to <option> using vueJs and bootsrap?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

How to set value in option using v-for? this is my code but I got error on `value="{{data.id}}"`  when I added the value.

these are lists that I want to set in select option.

```
  [{"id":1,"name":"test1"},{"id":2,"name":"test2"},{"id":3,"name":"test3"}]
```

[image]

Comment: anyway I got it instead of  value="{{data.id}}"  I used v-bind:value="data.id"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{{data[index].id}}` since it is a JS object.

Also, next time, paste the code so we can edit/test it directly. :)

Comment: Oh alright. You should make that an answer then and mark it or mark mine if mine works :)